# MVC TextAreaFor with value rendering empty box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea

I'm trying to generate a `TextArea` box with default value supplied by the controller.  Given this markup which calls a partial view:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction(
        "ContentBlock", "ContentBlock", 
            new TestSiteMvc.Models.ContentModel() { ContentID = 3 }
        );
}
```

Partial View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Title)
@Model.ContentHtml<br />
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ContentHtml)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContentHtml)
@Html.TextArea("ContentHtml2", Model.ContentHtml)
@Model.ContentHtml<br />
```

The resulting HTML rendered is:

```
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="Home Title" />
Home Page Content<br />
<textarea cols="20" id="ContentHtml" name="ContentHtml" rows="2"></textarea>
<input id="ContentHtml" name="ContentHtml" type="text" value="Home Page Content" />
<textarea cols="20" id="ContentHtml2" name="ContentHtml2" rows="2">Home Page Content</textarea>
Home Page Content<br />
```

So, it's clear the ContentHtml property is getting populated.  What I don't understand is why `TextAreaFor` is getting rendered with an empty value.  And to be clear, when I remove the line `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContentHtml)` as to not incur tags with the same id, the issue does not go away.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ContentBlock(Models.ContentModel mcontent) {

        mcontent = new Models.ContentModel() { 
            ContentID = 3,
            ContentHtml = "Home Page Content", 
            Title = "Home Title" };
        return PartialView(mcontent);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class ContentModel {

    public int ContentID { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ContentHtml { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate this at all.

Comment: Where is your controller code? Tested the view code using given viewmodel properties in question and it has worked, you need to provide controller action method to clear out textarea default value issue.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I added the controller and some additional code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET method has a parameter which is your model, so the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes `ContentModel` with default values and sets the value of `ContentID` to `3`. At this point all values are added to `ModelState` (the value of `ContentHtml` in `ModelState` is `null` - the default value for `string`). Updating the values of your properties does not affect the values in `ModelState`.

When you return the view, the `@Html.TextAreaFor()` first checks `ModelState`, which in your case is `null` so no value is rendered. (and if a value in `ModelState` is not found, the method then checks `ViewData`, and finally the actual value of your model property to determine what to render).

Note also that `@Html.TextArea("ContentHtml2", Model.ContentHtml)` works because it is not binding to a model property and your using an overload that specifically sets the value based on another property.

The correct approach, and easiest way to solve this is to change the controller method to

```
public ActionResult ContentBlock(int id)
{
    ContentModel model = new ContentModel()
    { 
        ContentID = id,
        ContentHtml = "Home Page Content", 
        Title = "Home Title"
    };
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and change the view code to

```
@{ Html.RenderAction( "ContentBlock", "ContentBlock", new { id = 3 }); }
```

Alternatively, you could add `ModelState.Clear()` as the first line of code in the controller method to remove all values from `ModelState` (the `TextAeaFor()` method will then get the value from the model property)

Comment: Thank you!  Changing the controller solved the issue.